# How to hide a field when its value is set to zero

Tags: entities, nodes

I want to hide a field on a node when its value is set to zero using a content type. Here is what I had done so far to achieve my goal.

```
function pay_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if ($node->type=='salary_info' && $op=='presave') {
    $public_holiday = $node->field_sstru_public_holiday[0]['value']; // here I get the value that I set to 0(No) or 1(YES) using a select list. 

    if ($public_holiday == 0) {
      $nid = node_load(207919); // load node where i want to unset this field   
      unset($nid->field_pd_public_holiday[0]); // here iam wrong and confused 
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message("HOLIDAY");
    }
  }
```

what should I do to unset my field?

Comment: you should not use unset to hide field. Instead you can  use `$node->field_sstru_public_holiday[0]['value'] = FALSE` . Here is a [reference](http://drupal.org/node/901382) i found.

Comment: @nit3ch instead i can use ? i had edited my code i.e. unset($nid->field_pd_public_holiday[0]);

Comment: @aashi edited the above comment please check.

Comment: @nit3cch i just want that the field whos valuet i set to 0(NO) should not be seen when the page is viwed..

Comment: @nit3ch the reference shows to hide or unset field when we use formid. But here iam working with hook_node_api. what to do?

Comment: so what's the problem just set it to false when $public_holiday is 0.   `if($public_holiday == 0)
      { 

         $nid = node_load(207919); // load node where i want to unset this field

    $nid->field_pd_public_holiday[0]) = False ; }`.

Comment: @nit3ch may be because iam using $op='presave'. what op should i use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8218/discussion-between-nit3ch-and-aashi)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using **presave** operation.

If you want to hide a field on node view you should use **view** operation.

So your code should be as the following code:

```
function pay_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {   
  if ($node->type=='salary_info' && $op=='view') {
    $public_holiday = $node->field_sstru_public_holiday[0]['value'];

    if ($public_holiday == 0) {
      // you don't need to load node again.
      unset($node->field_pd_public_holiday);    
    } else {
      drupal_set_message("HOLIDAY");
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to hide field on another content type or node using **presave** operation, then you need to load node and unset field value then save node again using `node_save` function

So your code should look as the following:

```
function pay_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if ($node->type=='salary_info' && $op=='presave') {
    $public_holiday = $node->field_sstru_public_holiday[0]['value']; // here I get the value that I set to 0(No) or 1(YES) using a select list. 

    if ($public_holiday == 0) {
      $node = node_load(207919); // load node by nid
      unset($node->field_pd_public_holiday[0]); // unset field from node object
      node_save($node); // save node after unsetting the unwanted field value. 
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message("HOLIDAY");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: field_pd_public_holiday -  this field is on another node i.e why iam loading it.

Comment: fields-field_sstru_public_holiday and field_pd_public_holiday are on different page. I want to hide field - field_pd_public_holiday when field -  fields-field_sstru_public_holiday is set to 0(NO).

Comment: @aashi updated my answer.